# how to use layoutinflator to implement multiple checkboxes?

Tags: android, checkbox, layout-inflater

I have used the following code,

```
LayoutInflater li=getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout linear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
View v=li.inflate(R.id.checkBox1,null);
linear.addView(v);
```

Is this code correct?
If not, please suggest me the correct one.

Comment: It's wrong... You have to inflate that xml layout but you are using component ID to inflate...

Comment: Well, it depends whether `checkbox1` is a layout file or an ID inside a layout file. Can you share your XML layout file too?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you are using in some adapter

```
 public class ViewHolder{
 private Checkbox chk1,chk2,chk3;
}
```

and when inflating your layout containing checkboxes

```
LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();;
ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
holder.chk1 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk_box1);

holder.chk2 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk_box2);

holder.chk3 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk_box3);

convertView.setTag(holder);
```